R paste() now collapses as.hexmode() zeroes
I'm generating hex colour codes. In R3.6.2
paste(as.hexmode(c(213,94,0)))

generates
 "d5" "5e" "00"

While in R4.4.1 it generates
 "d5" "5e" "0"

resulting in an invalid hexcode ("#d55e0") and broken code
paste() now seems not to recognise the 'hexmode' attribute - rather it treats the result of as.hexmode() as a simple integer. Is this change to be expected?

well,   the value of zero in hexadecimal is, after all,  just "0" , just as hexadecimal for 11 is just "B" .  I agree it's annoying when something (like color code format) expects exactly two digits of hexadecimal for a value.   Maybe what we need is a function as.bytemode  which forces the use of 8 bits.  Not to  show off :-), but my package bigBits  does allow you to specify the number of digita in the character-class output

Other possibility:   prettyunits::pretty_bytes

Yes this is expected. A change in R 4.2 was:

as.character(<obj>) for "hexmode" or "octmode" objects now fulfils the important basic rule as.character(x)[j] === as.character(x[j])

In R 3.6, as.character.hexmode(x) was a wrapper for format.hexmode(x):
x <- c(213, 94, 0)
as.character(as.hexmode(x[3])) # 0
as.character(as.hexmode(x))[3] # 00

However, in R ≥ 4.2, it is basically equivalent to sprintf("%x", as.integer(x)):
as.character(as.hexmode(x[3])) # 0
as.character(as.hexmode(x))[3] # 0

This apparently has surprising consequences for you and others relying on zero-padding. This message from Martin Maechler (R Core Team member) explains the rationale. In any case, to get the desired behaviour, you can use format.hexmode() directly:
format(as.hexmode(x), width = 2)
# [1] "d5" "5e" "00"

The behaviour of format.hexmode() is to automatically pad the width to the max digits of any value in the vector, which in this case is two, so width = 2 is not necessary here. However, it may be better to explicitly set with width argument cover all cases. For example, if you were generating the code for black, you would need to set width to get zero-padded output:
format(as.hexmode(c(0, 0, 0)))
# [1] "0" "0" "0"
format(as.hexmode(c(0, 0, 0)), width = 2)
# [1] "00" "00" "00"

Using format.hexmode() will replicate the R 3.6 paste() behaviour on both R ≥ 4.2 and <4.2.

What a, frankly, daft rationale, especially used to justify a breaking change in a minor release (… and of course once again not documented/announced as a breaking change). But that’s par for the course for R.

The reason you obtained 0 instead of 00 has been answered excellently in SamR's solution.
Here is just a workaround. You can use as.character.numeric_version rather than as.character
> as.character.numeric_version(as.hexmode(c(213, 94, 0)))
[1] "d5" "5e" "00"


This works for now and is perhaps nicer (certainly it's one less function call). But a word of warning is that the reason that paste() doesn't work anymore is that as.character() was updated so that as.character(x)[j] == as.character(x[j]). This isn't currently the case for as.character.numeric_version(), which is why this works. That seems inconsistent to me and it wouldn't astonish me if as.character.numeric_version() had a similar update in the future.

@SamR yes, you are right! it is working for now, but cannot guarantee the future :)

Digging into this further I found that after the update to as.character.hexmode() in R 4.2, as.character.POSIXt() got the same treatment in R 4.3. So the clock may be ticking :)
